# Killing a PID which is using a port

Tags: linux, shell

I am using below code to kill a process which is using a port number

```
port = sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:3030 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2;}'
if [ ! -z "$port" -a "$port" != " " ]; then
   sudo kill "$port"
fi
```

But it is saying `port: command not found`. What is causing the issue and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 6):

As it stands,

```
port = sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:3030 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2;}'
```

attempts to run a command `port` with parameters `= sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:3030` and pipe its output through `grep LISTEN` and then `awk '{print $2;}'`.

Use

```
port=$(sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:3030 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2;}')
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But may I know why it fails when space is given between `port`, `=` and `$`

Comment: If you put spaces around the `=`, the shell will again parse it as a command `port` with parameters `=` and the result of the command substitution. You cannot have spaces there if it is to be a variable assignment; the shell language does not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to roll this yourself: `fuser` on Linux will do it for you in a single command, and much more efficiently:

```
sudo fuser -n tcp -k 3030
```

Answer (score 0):

With just one line!

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3030`
```